# How much data can spring jdbc session hold

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, spring-session

I decided to use Spring JDBC Session for holding logged user information. The 'User' entity includes 'photo' field of type 'String'. Actually, I am storing user profile pictures in database as Base64 encoded String. User information are stored in the database without any problem. Spring JDBC session could hold user information including a photo of 20kb size. But when a user with photo of 52kb size wants to login, it gives an error-

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT INTO SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES(SESSION_PRIMARY_ID, ATTRIBUTE_NAME, ATTRIBUTE_BYTES) SELECT PRIMARY_ID, ?, ? FROM SPRING_SESSION WHERE SESSION_ID = ?]; Data truncation: Data too long for column 'ATTRIBUTE_BYTES' at row 1; nested exception is com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'ATTRIBUTE_BYTES' at row 1
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT INTO SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES(SESSION_PRIMARY_ID, ATTRIBUTE_NAME, ATTRIBUTE_BYTES) SELECT PRIMARY_ID, ?, ? FROM SPRING_SESSION WHERE SESSION_ID = ?]; Data truncation: Data too long for column 'ATTRIBUTE_BYTES' at row 1; nested exception is com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'ATTRIBUTE_BYTES' at row 1
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:104)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1443)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:862)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:917)
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.insertSessionAttributes(JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.java:483)
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.access$1300(JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.java:130)
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcIndexedSessionRepository$JdbcSession.lambda$save$10(JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.java:817)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionOperations.lambda$executeWithoutResult$0(TransactionOperations.java:68)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionOperations.executeWithoutResult(TransactionOperations.java:67)
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcIndexedSessionRepository$JdbcSession.save(JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.java:799)
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcIndexedSessionRepository$JdbcSession.access$200(JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.java:631)
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.save(JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.java:409)
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.save(JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.java:130)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.commitSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:225)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.access$100(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:192)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:144)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:82)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'ATTRIBUTE_BYTES' at row 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:104)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1092)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1040)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1347)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1025)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$update$0(JdbcTemplate.java:867)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:617)
    ... 38 more
```

Comment: Why would you store an image in session?

Comment: Actually, I am new to Spring. It was easy for me to store the full user information in the session and display the profile info in web page. It would be great if I knew a better way to accomplish the task.

Comment: I couldn't figure it out. Therefore, I have replaced the Spring session implementation with Redis Server. Redis seems effective in storing large amount of data.